# How should I understand 〜ぬ時は?

Tags: translation, manga, sentence

[image]

I'm confused on this picture.
The question is, my teacher told me that

> 来ない時は(約束した日時または時間)
>
> 分かっておるであろうな(あなたはどうなるのか分かっているはずだ)

But I don't understand how can it change into this?
I understand about the translated version from my teacher now but when I was trying on translation on the first time it went like this.

> "The time that you doesn't come, You're understand?" It's weird right?

But from my teacher, I can understand it now.

Except I don't know how to change `来ぬ時間` into　`約束した時間`.

Is it some kind of grammar?

Especially `分かっておるであろうな` into `あなたはどうなるのか分かっているはずだ`

I can understand that わかっておる can translate into わかっている but It's followed by であろうな.

What does it mean, and how can it turn into `あなたはどうなるのか分かっているはずだ`?

Answer (score 5):

It's a good question. :)

> 来ない時は(約束した日時または時間)
>   分かっておるであろうな(あなたはどうなるのか分かっているはずだ)

来ない時は is actually equivalent to a ***condition/premise***; **もし**来なければ**どうなるか**. どうなるか is only *implied*, and continues to the question, 分かっているだろうな, which is to remind (you) what follows if (you) don't come, saying it in an intimidating tone like an old sage.

Comment: I understand now, Thanks you so much.
that means if I see sentence like　食べないときは i can also think it as
もしたべなかれば by looking at context.

Answer (score 5):

It literally says:

「来ぬ時は」 (≂ 来ない時は) -- "When you don't come / If you don't show up..."
「（どうなるか）分かっておるであろうな」 (≂ 分かっているだろうな) -- "I suppose you know (what will happen). / You know (what will happen), do you not?"

分かっておるであろうな, or 分かっているだろうな in modern/standard Japanese, is used as a *threat* here: "You see what happens?" i.e. "You better not!" -- "You should come! (or else...)" in this case.

The way the person speaks (来ぬ for 来ない, おるであろう for いるだろう) is the so-called [老人語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E) / old man's speech in fiction, a kind of [役割語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%B9%E5%89%B2%E8%AA%9E) / role language in fiction.

Comment: Thank you so much.
after I change it into
来ないときはわかっているでしょうな？
it become more understandable.